# Download blob storage and return Json object

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-blob-storage, memorystream

I am trying to download a `.json` blob that I have stored in a container in the `Azure Storage` using `Newtonsoft.Json` to write it to an object.

I am doing this by calling:

```
(CloudBlockBlob) blob.DownloadToStream(stream);
```

However, instead of writing the stream to a file in the local app directory, I want to return the json `object` doing `Json(result)`

This is what I have tried:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    blob.DownloadToStream(stream);

    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            result = serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader);
        }
    }
}
```

At the end my `jsonTextReader` variable is empty and the object `null`

What can I do to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Try resetting the stream's position to `0` after `blob.DownloadToStream(stream);`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! If you post the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please reset the stream's position to `0` after reading the blob into the stream. So your code would be:

```
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            blob.DownloadToStream(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;//resetting stream's position to 0
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                {
                    var result = serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Always specify what libraries are used in your example - add using ;)

Comment: Hi, when I used this code it worked but the output is json object with '{{' and I cannot convert it to Datatable !! any suggestions please ?

Comment: @EmnaJaoua Please ask a new question instead of asking it in comments. Please share all the details you can.

Comment: I apologize for the short comment. I solved my issue by modifyingthe variable result 
 = @"[" + result + "]". So I could convert it to dataTable.

Answer (score 16):

Both the question and accepted answer start by copying the entire stream into a `MemoryStream` which is effectively a big byte array in memory. This step is unnecessary - it's more memory-efficient to stream the blob data directly to the object without buffering the bytes first:

```
using (var stream = await blob.OpenReadAsync())
using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    result = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<T>(jr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Azure.Storage.Blobs` library has been a moving target for years. Here's the latest as of Oct. 2023.

```
BlobDownloadResult downloadResult = await blockBlob.DownloadContentAsync();
var plainTextResult = downloadResult.Content.ToString();
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(plainTextResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't care for streaming and want a short and concise way:

```
var json = await blockBlob.DownloadTextAsync();

var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```